# Mantis Bug Tracker Attachments File Format

Tags: file, mantis

May I know if files attached in Mantis Bug Tracker is in binary format only? Is it configurable to be saved in the original file format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The files are stored as they are uploaded, no transformation is applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I wanted to ask was if it is possible to save those uploaded files directly onto the server's file system. And I have found out how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Wilson - good to hear that your problem is solved. Might be worth posting it as an answer here so that others benefit as well.